# edtor.html restricting anchor in AEM

Tags: anchor, aem, preview, author

I am using aem anchor from RTE. Problem is its not working in author mode, so below url is working :

```
http://localhost:4502/content/home/anchortest.html#myanchor
```

whereas this one is not working (preview mode) :

```
http://localhost:4502/editor.html/content/home/anchortest.html#myanchor
```

Please help,
Thanks in advance

Comment: `editor.html` displays the whole page in an iframe, which may be the reason your anchor doesn't work as expected. What is happening exactly? Does the element not come into focus when you click the link?

Comment: Yes @toniedzwiedz its simply doing nothing with {editor.html}.

Comment: The Page remains the same with {editor.html} on link.

Comment: Does the element you want to focus actually render with an `id` of `myanchor`?

Comment: Yes, its mapped correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since author mode in AEM auto generates the iFrame of the content page so it doesnt take its source url along with the anchor hash automatically. This is why its not working in presense of {editor.html} while it works on publish environment or url without {editor.html}